# How to get the architect of the CNN model from Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a model using https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/

When I run the following code:

```
import tensorflow

model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model("converted_savedmodel/model.savedmodel")
model.summary()
```

I get

```
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
sequential_1 (Sequential)    (None, 1280)              410208    
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_3 (Sequential)    (None, 2)                 128300    
=================================================================
Total params: 538,508
Trainable params: 524,428
Non-trainable params: 14,080
```

---

How can I get more details, for example, like the following?

```
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 5, 5, 256)         295168    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 2, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               131200    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 128)               0
```

Comment: try `model.layers[0].summary()`

Comment: I get `Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
model1 (Functional)          (None, 7, 7, 1280)        410208    
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_Glo (None, 1280)              0         `

Comment: You can use [get_layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#get_layer) to retrieve a layer information on either its name or index. For more details you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64415859/14290681) answer. Thanks!